# Starting a broken laptop motherboard

Tags: laptop, motherboard

I have an old laptop motherboard and i was trying to add external power button and i broke the solder pad for the internal button (soldered onto a motherboard). Now i am wondering is there a way to start my computer using something like the serial port. I checked and wake on lan is not working. after a sucessfull startup i will enable "start when power atached" in the bios. On the pc i have: 1X audio output, 2X USB2.0, 1X USB3.0, 1X ethernet port, 1X hdmi port and a serial communication port

Comment: Without knowing anything about the laptop or the BIOS settings, this is impossible to answer.  It is unlikely though. Your best bet would be to try to start with a wire.